# okhttp - HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Failed to find a trusted cert that signed Certificate:

Tags: android, rest, ssl, okhttp

Hello i got this exception whenever calling a specific `Rest` endPoint but i'm stucked at `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException`, i get this exception only in api level 21 (Android 5.0).

we're also ipmlementing in our app a custom trust manager for http client

```
fun OkHttpClient.Builder.ignoreAllSSLErrors(): OkHttpClient.Builder {
    val naiveTrustManager = object : X509TrustManager {
        override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate> = arrayOf()
        override fun checkClientTrusted(certs: Array<X509Certificate>, authType: String) = Unit
        override fun checkServerTrusted(certs: Array<X509Certificate>, authType: String) = Unit
    }

    val insecureSocketFactory = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2").apply {
        val trustAllCerts = arrayOf<TrustManager>(naiveTrustManager)
        init(null, trustAllCerts, SecureRandom())
    }.socketFactory

    sslSocketFactory(insecureSocketFactory, naiveTrustManager)
    hostnameVerifier(HostnameVerifier { _, _ -> true })
    return this
}
```

and this is the stackTrace of the exception:

```
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Failed to find a trusted cert that signed Certificate:
        Data:
            Version: 3 (0x2)
            Serial Number:
                13:ea:28:70:5b:f4:ec:ed:0c:36:63:09:80:61:43:36
        Signature Algorithm: sha384WithRSAEncryption
            Issuer: C=SE, O=AddTrust AB, OU=AddTrust External TTP Network, CN=AddTrust External CA Root
            Validity
                Not Before: May 30 10:48:38 2000 GMT
                Not After : May 30 10:48:38 2020 GMT
            Subject: C=US, ST=New Jersey, L=Jersey City, O=The USERTRUST Network, CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
```

i can add more details if needed, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is because the CA cert has expired on older devices. See [How to trust SSL certificates with cross-signed root expired on android <= 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62275157/how-to-trust-ssl-certificates-with-cross-signed-root-expired-on-android-5)

But it's unclear why your insecure settings aren't working.  You haven't provided a usable reproduction, so it's hard to do more than guess otherwise.